# Invalid training data. X and Y must have the same number of observations

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification, lstm

I have long ECG signals segmented into 300 points segments/heartbeats. I want to use CNN for feature extraction with a bidirectional LSTM layer for classification.
I have the following network:

```
inputSize=[1 300 1]; %the heartbeat size
Layers=[
sequenceInputLayer(inputSize,'Normalization', 'zscore', 'Name','input'); 
sequenceFoldingLayer('Name','fold')

convolution2dLayer([1 7], 16,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv1')
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn1')
maxPooling2dLayer([1 2],'stride',[1 2],'Name','mpool1')

convolution2dLayer([1 7], 32,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv2')
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn2')
reluLayer('Name','relu1')
maxPooling2dLayer([1 2],'stride',[1 2],'Name','mpool2')

convolution2dLayer([1 5], 64,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv3') 
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn3')
reluLayer('Name','relu2')

convolution2dLayer([1 5], 128,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv4')
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn4')
reluLayer('Name','relu3')

convolution2dLayer([1 3], 256,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv5')  
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn5')
reluLayer('Name','relu4')
maxPooling2dLayer([1 2],'stride',[1 2],'Name','mpool3')

convolution2dLayer([1 3], 512,'stride',[1 1], 'padding','same','Name','conv6')
batchNormalizationLayer('Name','bn6')
reluLayer('Name','relu5')
maxPooling2dLayer([1 2],'stride',[1 2],'Name','mpool4')

sequenceUnfoldingLayer('Name','unfold')
flattenLayer('Name','flatten')

bilstmLayer(200,'Name','lstm')

reluLayer('Name','relu6')
fullyConnectedLayer(256,'Name','fc1')
reluLayer('Name','relu7')
fullyConnectedLayer(128,'Name','fc2')
reluLayer('Name','relu8')
fullyConnectedLayer(5,'Name','fc3')
softmaxLayer('Name','softmax')
classificationLayer('Name','classification')
];
```

I connect the layers using:

```
lgraph = layerGraph(Layers);
lgraph = connectLayers(lgraph,'fold/miniBatchSize','unfold/miniBatchSize');
```

When I train the network I have the following error:

```
Error using trainNetwork (line 170)
Invalid training data. X and Y must have the same number of observations.
Error in CNN_LSTM (line 152)
convnet = trainNetwork(Xtrain,Ytrain,lgraph,options);
```

Can someone please tell me how could I solve this error?
Xtrain has the size 1 300 1 91147 (it contains 91147 segments of 300 datapoints each)
Y train has the size 91147 1

Comment: I am unfamiliar with NNs. That said, the output suggests that one (or more) layer(s) are not connected. Can you check whether you properly connected all layers to each other?

Comment: @Adriaan I checked the Connections of lgraph and everything seems all right. The input is connected to the fold layer and the fold layer is connected to both the first convolutional layer and unfold layer. Everything after is connected in the order from above (Layers).

Comment: You tried to check the size of Xtrain,Ytrain,lgraph ? Do they match ? ... error is about data size mismatch. You tried to check the MATLAB example in the online help, and see how these variables are given to trainNetwork.